# What does Cross-Platform Development mean in Embedded System?

Tags: embedded, cross-compiling

I did an interview in a company, and someone from HR asked me this question, but I do not know its relation with Embedded System, how I use it?

I searched for this topic in different sites but I did not find anything related to Embedded Systems.

Answer (score 1):

Definition - What does Cross-Platform Development mean?

Cross-platform development is the practice of developing software products or services for multiple platforms or software environments. Engineers and developers use various methods to accommodate different operating systems or environments for one application or product.

[definition](http://Have%20a%20look%20at%20this)

Comment: I know the definition of it , I need to know how to use it in Embedded Systems.

Comment: As said "developing software products or services for multiple platforms or software environments". In this case it depends the product but you can have different processor architectures that requires different things. ARM vs everything else for example.

Comment: And as for cross-compiling, it simply means developing in one system (Windows PC) for another system (microcontroller). Meaning that almost all embedded development is using cross-compiling, save for upper end systems that run Linux or such on-board.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, your development (Host) on X86-x64 PC platform but your target development (board, device, ..) is ARM, PowerPC,.. platform. In this case, your development on the Host, cross-compile on the Host and then port to the target.